# Soft Cosine Similarity between two sentences

Tags: python, gensim, cosine-similarity

I am trying to find a simple way to calculate soft cosine similarity between two sentences.

Here is my attempt and learning:

```
from gensim.matutils import softcossim

sent_1 = 'Dravid is a cricket player and a opening batsman'.split()
sent_2 = 'Leo is a cricket player too He is a batsman,baller and keeper'.split()

print(softcossim(sent_1, sent_2, similarity_matrix))
```

I'm unable to understand about `similarity_matrix`. Please help me find so, and henceforth the soft cosine similarity in python.

Answer (score 3):

As of the current version of Gensim, 3.8.3, some of the method calls from both the question and previous answers have been deprecated. Those functions deprecated have been removed from the 4.0.0 beta. Can't seem to provide code in a reply to @EliadL, so adding a new comment.

The current method for solving this problem in Gensim 3.8.3 and 4.0.0 is as follows:

```py
import gensim.downloader as api
from gensim import corpora
from gensim.matutils import softcossim

sent_1 = 'Dravid is a cricket player and a opening batsman'.split()
sent_2 = 'Leo is a cricket player too He is a batsman,baller and keeper'.split()

# Download the FastText model
fasttext_model300 = api.load('fasttext-wiki-news-subwords-300')

# Prepare a dictionary and a corpus.
documents = [sent_1, sent_2]
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(documents)

# Prepare the similarity matrix
similarity_index = WordEmbeddingSimilarityIndex(fasttext_model300)
similarity_matrix = SparseTermSimilarityMatrix(similarity_index, dictionary)

# Convert the sentences into bag-of-words vectors.
sent_1 = dictionary.doc2bow(sent_1)
sent_2 = dictionary.doc2bow(sent_2)

# Compute soft cosine similarity
print(similarity_matrix.inner_product(sent_1, sent_2, normalized=True))
#> 0.68463486
```

For users of Gensim v. 3.8.3, I've also found this [Notebook](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/release-3.8.3/docs/notebooks/soft_cosine_tutorial.ipynb) to be helpful in understanding Soft Cosine Similarity and how to apply Soft Cosine Similarity using Gensim.

As of now, for users of Gensim 4.0.0 beta this [Notebook](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/soft_cosine_tutorial.ipynb) is the one to look at.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to save and load the similarity_matrix from file? I have been trying the SparseTermSimilarityMatrix.save function, but I keep getting errors related to the inner_dot_product of the WordEmbeddingSimilarityIndex.

Comment: @grumpyTofu - using Gensim 3.8.3 and the example notebook from the https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/soft_cosine_tutorial.ipynb saving a Similarity Matrix is just `similarity_matrix.save('mysmfile')` If you need more help, probably better to open a new question with your error, code and details about your environment

Comment: As the author of the soft cosine measure (SCM) implementation in Gensim, I approve this answer. Additionally, if you have a corpus, you want to train a TF-IDF model with the SCM: If not for the document representation, than at least as the third parameter of `SparseTermSimilarityMatrix`. This way, the matrix will be constructed from the rarest most informative terms rather than in alphabetic order, which has been shown to give better results on text classification and information retrieval tasks.

Comment: Bumped into an error for some reason running `similarity_matrix.inner_product(sent_1, sent_2, normalized=True)` but it worked after changing it to the following: `similarity_matrix.inner_product(sent_1, sent_2,  normalized = (True,False)` .

Comment: On top of what @Cosq mentioned, there is one more issue that the line `from gensim.matutils import softcossim` is useless in here.

Answer (score 2):

Going by [this tutorial](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/gensim-tutorial/#18howtocomputesimilaritymetricslikecosinesimilarityandsoftcosinesimilarity):

```
import gensim.downloader as api
from gensim import corpora
from gensim.matutils import softcossim

sent_1 = 'Dravid is a cricket player and a opening batsman'.split()
sent_2 = 'Leo is a cricket player too He is a batsman,baller and keeper'.split()

# Download the FastText model
fasttext_model300 = api.load('fasttext-wiki-news-subwords-300')

# Prepare a dictionary and a corpus.
documents = [sent_1, sent_2]
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(documents)

# Prepare the similarity matrix
similarity_matrix = fasttext_model300.similarity_matrix(dictionary)

# Convert the sentences into bag-of-words vectors.
sent_1 = dictionary.doc2bow(sent_1)
sent_2 = dictionary.doc2bow(sent_2)

# Compute soft cosine similarity
print(softcossim(sent_1, sent_2, similarity_matrix))
#> 0.7909639717134869
```

Comment: As of the current version of Gensim, 3.8.3, some of the method calls used in this answer have been deprecated. Those functions deprecated have been removed from the 4.0.0 beta.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SoftCosineSimilarity class in gensim.similarities in gensim 4.0.0 upwards

```
from gensim.similarities import SoftCosineSimilarity
#Calculate Soft Cosine Similarity between the query and the documents.
def find_similarity(query,documents):
  query = dictionary.doc2bow(query)
  index = SoftCosineSimilarity(
    [dictionary.doc2bow(document) for document in documents],
    similarity_matrix)
  similarities = index[query]
  return similarities
```

Comment: Did you maybe missed "s" in document, in def find_similarity(query,document):?