# How to avoid downloading glove-wiki-gigaword-300 or any other word vector package everytime?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, stanford-nlp

My use case : I get input (a sentence) from the user and need to find similar sentences from my repository file. I will be giving back three best matching sentences to the user.

As of now, I have coded rule based logics in python and it is working fine for lexical matches.

I am trying to improve the logic with semantic matching, soft cosine in specific.

I am planning to use the code which will look like : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65813988/11049287

My question is should I have to execute the below download statement

```
api.load('glove-wiki-gigaword-300'))
```

everytime I execute the code or any other work-arounds?
Is it possible to save the file?

Comment: Did you test the code and find out that it really downloads every time? I would expect that it already cached the result.

Comment: I will be moving the code to execute from Azure. So, I am afraid the download will happen again and again.

Answer (score 0):

you can download the model once:

```
api.load("glove-wiki-gigaword-300", return_path=True)
```

The output will be the local path to the model.
Something like this:

```
>>> /home/user/gensim-data/glove-wiki-gigaword-300/glove-wiki-gigaword-300.gz
```

And then:

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(<localpath>, binary=False)
```

Don't forget to change the 'localpath' for a real path string.